# Issue with accents in trying to add data to MySQL from TXT fil in php ... encoding issue?

Tags: php, encoding, base64

I have a TXT file called ADDEDA.TXT (actually a CSV) that I need to parse and add to a MySQL.  Accents are added as ? .

I tried to change encoding  as such `$content = encode_utf8($content);`
Also `mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8');`
Using the following function, the encoding would be BASE64

```
function detectFileEncoding($filePath){

    $fopen=fopen($filePath,'r');

    $row = fgets($fopen);
    $encodings = mb_list_encodings();
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding( $row, "UTF-8, ASCII, Windows-1252, Windows-1254" );//these are my favorite encodings

    if($encoding !== false) {
        $key = array_search($encoding, $encodings) !== false;
        if ($key !== false)
            unset($encodings[$key]);
        $encodings = array_values($encodings);
    }

    $encKey = 0;
    while ($row = fgets($fopen)) {
        if($encoding == false){
            $encoding = $encodings[$encKey++];
        }

        if(!mb_check_encoding($row, $encoding)){
            $encoding =false;
            rewind($fopen);
        }

    }

    return $encoding;
}
```

Comment: Text encoding is _metadata_ that must be known and tracked along with the file. It _cannot_ be reliably detected, and any function that purports to do so is making an educated _guess_ and should not be relied upon.

Comment: By `encode_utf8`, I'm assuming you mean `utf8_encode`. If so, you should know that that [function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) is [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_utf8_decode_and_utf8_encode)

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: interesting, im on the west coast and rarely run into accents in code.. i found this thread on sitepoint that seems similar https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/accented-characters-into-sql-table/204153/4